# Acceptable temperature variation in heated bed

Tags: troubleshooting, heated-bed, temperature

Ever since my original Creality CR-10S Pro heated bed quit and was replaced, I have had trouble with bed adhesion and printed first layer material warping using PLA and auto bed leveling.

I am getting bed temperature variation between 71 °C (160 °F) to 76 °C (169 °F) throughout the 320x310 mm bed.  Is this amount of temperature variation typical? I don't have any measured temperature variation data for the original heated bed, so don't have any reference data to compare.

Note: the manual (and about every internet site visited) suggested 60 °C for bed temperature for PLA, but I never could get any material adhesion until I raised the bed temperature to 80 °C using the stock heated bed. I have had no real issues with bed adhesion until the original heated bed died after about one year of heavy use with 10+ 1 kg filament reels.

Not sure how much more I can do to determine, what is suggested as "my bed adhesion problem".

Have tried everything:

- painter tape worked the best, until trying to get the tape off of print
- glass with dimples
- glass with a glue stick
- new bed sticker
- cleaning after every print
- varying print head height.

The only thing left is the filament. manufacture.

Through all my tests it takes 80 °C to get the first layer to stick and if I reduce temp to 60 °C after the first layer, the print comes off.   Could a poor performing set of fans cause this to occur?

Comment: What surface do you print on? Do you use adhesive? Do you clean and degrease the bed? The surface can change/degrade over time, there could be a contaminant. Also ambient temperature being cold can cause warping issues that aren’t there when it’s warm.

Comment: you can insulate the bottom of the bed to help uniformity. Also, pre-heating for longer should help. the corners will never be the exact same temp as the center, but 5deg is a bit on the high side for a difference. Also, that's WAY too hot, no wonder your old one gave out. Get one of those flexible magnetic build plate covers; those are way easy to adhere to, and you can drop your temp to 50 at the max.

Answer (score 2):

80 °C is way too hot for the bed with PLA. The highest bed temperature you can use without serious deformation of the printed part is around the glass transition temperature of the material - 55-60 °C for PLA. And even that will seriously inhibit the cooling of layers near the bed. Below 40 °C or even unheated is ideal to avoid warping.

Go back to reasonable bed temperatures and figure out the root cause of your adhesion problem rather than trying to use heat as a workaround for poor adhesion. Maybe your surface is bad and needs to be replaced, or just in need of cleaning.